# Update Opportunity Stage when DocuSign Envelope Status is 'Signed'

Tags: trigger, docusign

I am very new to triggers but would like to set up a simple trigger. Any help is greatly appreciated! Pseudo code below.

on insert or update

```
if (Docusign Envelope Status is equal to 'Signed' AND Opportunity Status does not equal ‘Agreement Signed Pending Rollout’){

     update Opportunity Stage to ‘Agreement Signed Pending Rollout’

}
```

Will this work?
How should I go about compiling the trigger?

```
variables                        API Name
Docusign Envelope Status         dsfs__Envelope_Status__c   
DocuSign Oppty                   dsfs__Opportunity__c
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple trigger will do the trick.

```
trigger opportunityStage on dsfs__Opportunity__c(before insert, before update){
    for(dsfs__Opportunity__c o : trigger.new){
        if(o.dsfs__Envelope_Status__c == 'Signed' && o.stage != 'Agreement Signed Pending Rollout'){
            o.stage = 'Agreement Signed Pending Rollout'
        }           
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. **Why used before triggers?** When we use before triggers, the values are not yet saved to database and any changes we made in trigger will get saved to database without any extra DML.
2. **What is trigger.new?** It is trigger context variable which holds the list of currently modified or inserted records.
3. **Why `==` in if condition but `=` in next line?** `==` is comparison operator which is used to compare two values. `=` is assignment operator which is used to assign value in right hand side to left hand variable.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Providing your information I assume that the field `dsfs__Envelope_Status__c` and `dsfs__Opportunity__c` are on the Opportunity SObject. If so the trigger should look something like:

```
  OpportinityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update){

        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new ) {   

        if(o.dsfs__Envelope_Status__c=='Signed' && o.StageName!='Agreement Signed Pending Rollout')
          o.StageName='Agreement Signed Pending Rollout';

      }
    }
```